# form that sends an http request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bootstrap form that takes user input, I want it to send data as json to an arbitrary HTTP endpoint. Can it be achieved without reloading of the page? So the form just floats away and nothing else happens? I'm no sure what to google for.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3.0 WebApp on Azure.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, that's exactly what [`AJAX`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) is designed for.

Comment: You have an action specified in form tag like here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp , but what you need is something like this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jquery

```
$.ajax({
url: "Your End Point",
context: document.body,
success: function(){
  'Whatever you need it to do'
}
});
```

Or make a HTTPRequest in JavaScript

Comment: how do i pass form data to this function\ajax query\whatever it is called?

Comment: On your form do an OnSubmit eg:  onsubmit="myFunction()" and wrap that ajax call in the function you are calling

Comment: Please don't. Use an unobtrusive event handler. In jQuery, that would be something like `$('#myForm').on('submit', function () { /* AJAX */ }` or with vanilla JS `document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', function () { /* AJAX */ })`.